# Floating-point: FLT_HAS_SUBNORM is 0 => subnormal value arises => unspecified behavior?

Tags: c, floating-point, ieee-754, unspecified-behavior

If `FLT_HAS_SUBNORM is 0` and if during execution of the FP operation (add, mul, div, etc.) a subnormal value arises (or if a subnormal value is given as input to these FP operations), then the FP engine's implementation (i.e. HW implementation [FPU], SW implementation [SW FP library], mixed HW-SW implementation [SW FP library using HW instructions followed by additional SW post-processing]) can:

- detect such subnormal values and set them to zeros (i.e. `flash-to-zero` policy / logic);
- do nothing [special] (leading to unpredictable output result values).

Question: can someone provide a correct argumentation (better if strengthened by references to `C` / `IEEE 754` standards) convincing that the behavior of this case does fall into `unspecified behavior` category?

Note: ISO/IEC 9899:202x (E) working draft — February 5, 2020 N2479:

> 3.4.4
> unspecified behavior
>
> behavior, that results from the use of an unspecified value, or other behavior upon which this document provides two or more possibilities and imposes no further requirements on which is chosen in any instance

Comment: The C standard does not specify floating-point behavior in detail, but any floating-point implementation is going to “do something“ with operation in which the real-number result lies between zero and the small positive representable value. Generally, it will round it according to some rounding rule, which may be toward zero, toward nearest (with a secondary rule about ties), toward +∞, or others, and/or it will generate an exception. There are not really any implementations that “do nothing.”

Comment: @EricPostpischil, thanks! Under  “do nothing” I've meant "do nothing special" (i.e. do not execute any extra logic dedicated to even detect subnormal values). Then, if the C standard does not say exactly `unspecified behavior`, which behavior is better characterizes this case? IEEE Std 754-2008 mentions `unspecified` only once and not related to the case described above.

Answer (score 0):

Replying to myself.

In this case:

1. The behavior is *not* unspecified.
2. The behavior is defined by implementation of the FP operation. Hence, the behavior is *implementation-defined*.
3. Since the logic for detecting and processing subnormal numbers is absent (`XXX_HAS_SUBNORM` is 0), then the output result is *indeterminate*.
4. (extra) This case should be seen as "user error" (and violation of `XXX_HAS_SUBNORM is 0`).